# Do Breaking Bad and Firefly have the same intro music?

Tags: breaking-bad, soundtrack, firefly

I know that the intro for Breaking Bad only has a few notes in it but they are remarkably similar to those in ["The Ballad of Serenity"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmyO2xuI1qI) from Firefly. If it is the case that they are connected, is there anything behind this?

Comment: Very different after listening back granted. But they seem to evoke the same feeling.....?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are similar, since the intro and show music for Breaking Bad has a heavy southwest influence ([according to the composer](http://blogs.amctv.com/breaking-bad/2008/04/interview-with-dave-porter/)), and the music for Firefly... well, it's made for a western in space so there's going to be that heavy southwest influence as well.

However... 
The [Intro to Breaking Bad](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F1HNuAE9WdU) was written by [Dave Porter](http://www.reddit.com/r/breakingbad/comments/1c8j4y/i_am_composer_dave_porter_best_known_for_my_work/) and doesn't really have a title.

The [Intro to Firefly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D7vS4z6ngQo) was written by [Joss Whedon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joss_Whedon) and performed by [Sonny Rhodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonny_Rhodes).

They are different songs.

Comment: If I remember correctly Joss Whedon actually played the guitar in the final recording...