# What is the theme music of Breaking Bad?

Tags: breaking-bad, soundtrack

Where does the theme of Breaking Bad (intros and sometimes during the episodes) come from? Is it a song or a short piece written specifically for this show? Also can it be found on any official CD collections?

I think the longest version of the theme can be heard in the end of Granite State (s05e15) episode.

Comment: See also: [Do Breaking Bad and Firefly have the same intro music?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/13759/1876)

Comment: Hoziers song called 'It Will Come Back' reminds me of the intro, its sort of similar

Comment: should listen "El mulato" of Enrique Bunbury, the sound is very similar.

Comment: I think the Breaking Bad theme sounds very like "Chan Chan" by the Buena Vista Social Club

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's an original piece written specifically for the show, written by Dave Porter. The title of the song is simply, "Breaking Bad Theme". There are a [few CDs](http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&field-keywords=breaking%20bad%20soundtrack&index=blended&link_code=qs&sourceid=Mozilla-search&tag=mozilla-20) available with music from the show, one featuring music written specifically for the show.

Answer (score 4):

MattD is absolutely correct, you can meet the composer [here](http://blogs.wsj.com/speakeasy/2013/09/24/meet-the-composer-behind-the-eerie-breaking-bad-theme/tab/print/):

> Dave Porter created that opening theme and has scored the show
>   throughout its five-year run. A composer who began his career as an
>   assistant in the studio of Philip Glass, he is currently working with
>   filmmaker M. Night Shyamalan on the TV series “Wayward Pines,” a
>   thriller expected to air on Fox next year.

Answer (score -5):

The base from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJGL1hdl8Cw) Argentinian song.

Comment: Do you have any link to back up your answer?